# How to show different page the second time the visitor clicks a link

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a gallery page with several thumbnails. If a visitor clicks on a thumbnail the full image shows in new page. 
What I have in mind is that I show the full image to the first and second clicked thumbnails. If the visitor clicks on another thumbnail I want him to see not the full image but another page where I could load a registration or something else.
If this involves php or javascript please have in mind I'm noob.

Comment: It will always be easy for a user to send a request that makes it look like they've never visited the page before. All you'll be able to do is have an illusion of security, so while this is fine to *suggest* that a user registers, you can't *force* them to this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from cookies you could use the session data. https://www.php.net/session_write_close

```
//setting session
$_SESSION['click_count'] = 2;
session_write_close();

//getting session
$count = $_SESSION['click_count'];
```

It is possible to modify cookies, but harder for a user to change the session.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example for a php Cookie

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["ClickedCount"]))
{
$count+=1;
setcookie("ClickedCount",$count);
}else{
  $count= 0;
setcookie("ClickedCount",$count);}
?>
```

then you can retrive this cookie value in your event handler like this

```
<?php
if ($_COOKIE["ClickedCount"] = 1 ){
//do something 
}else{
//do something else
}
?>
```

Comment: Does this code add cookie only if a link is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, just modified Hakim code,

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_COOKIE["ClickedCount"])){      
        setcookie("ClickedCount",'visted', time()+3600); /* expire in 1 hour */
    }else{

       header("location:differentpageurl");
    }
?>
```